# SQL Query getting result Joining Two Table with matching 2 different values

Tags: sql

I have 2 table
1st Table is

## Customer Number, Customer Name, Place, State

- 1,                 ABC,           DEL,     DL
- 2,                 ABD,           PNP,     HR
- 3,                 ABE,           LDH,     PB

Another Table

## Code,      Description

- DEL,       Delhi
- DL  ,      Delhi
- PNP  ,     Panipat
- HR    ,    Haryana
- LDH    ,   Ludhiana
- PB      ,  Pubjab

I need a SQL Query which shows the following Result

## Customer Number, Customer Name, Place, State

1. 1,                 ABC,           DELHI,     DELHI
2. 2,                 ABD,    PANIPAT,   HARYANA
3. 3,                 ABE,           LUDHIANA,  PUNJAB

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you need to join `Table2` twice on `Table1` because are two dependent columns on it.

```
SELECT  a.CustomerNumber,
        a.CustomerName,
        b.Description Place,
        c.Description State
FROM    Table1 a
        INNER JOIN Table2 b
            ON a.Place = b.Code
        INNER JOIN Table2 c
            ON a.State = c.Code
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/afd9dd/1)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

OUTPUT

```
╔════════════════╦══════════════╦══════════╦═════════╗
║ CUSTOMERNUMBER ║ CUSTOMERNAME ║  PLACE   ║  STATE  ║
╠════════════════╬══════════════╬══════════╬═════════╣
║              1 ║ ABC          ║ Delhi    ║ Delhi   ║
║              2 ║ ABD          ║ Panipat  ║ Haryana ║
║              3 ║ ABE          ║ Ludhiana ║ Pubjab  ║
╚════════════════╩══════════════╩══════════╩═════════╝
```